# useContext with React Hooks to set state of parent from child

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I got a bit of a simple question that I can't seem to resolve no matter how much I've research the docs and similar questions.

This is my app component (parent component)

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import Search from './search/search.jsx';

export const SearchContext = createContext();

function App() {
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

    return (
        <div id='app-main-container'>
            <SearchContext.Provider value = {setKeyword}>
                <Search />
            </SearchContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

This is my search component which is utilizing the SearchContext created in the app component

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import SearchContext from '../app.jsx';

export default function SearchBar(props) {
    const setKeyword = useContext(SearchContext);

    return (
        <div id='search-bar-container'>
            <input onChange={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)}></input>
        </div>
    );
};
```

What I'm trying to do is essential set the state of `keyword` in my app component by using the `setKeyword` function which I'm passing down via the `value` of the `SearchContext.provider` and calling during the `onChange` event. Main reason for doing this is to avoid passing down `setKeyword` as a prop. What am I missing here? When I do `console.log(setKeyword)` it returns `undefined` which means I'm either not passing my argument correctly or I'm accessing it incorrectly.

Comment: import { SearchContext } from '../app.jsx';

Comment: That was it! Thanks @HenryLe. I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 1):

```
import { SearchContext } from '../app.jsx';
```

Forgot to destructure the key out